# how to make strtolower and space to - on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello guys im newbie so i really need your help
i want to make link like this:

https://floristshop.msi-staging.tk/store/4/bunga-indah

but what i got is like this:

https://floristshop.msi-staging.tk/store/4/Bunga%20Indah

and this is my code:

```
 <p>
  @foreach($stores as $store)
    <a href="{{ env('FRONTEND_URL') . "/store/$store->id/$store->name"}}"><label>{{ env('FRONTEND_URL') . "/store/$store->id/$store->name"}}  </label></a>
  @endforeach
 </p>
```

I really need some help thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel provides very nice helper for creating slugs.

you can try `str_slug('Laravel 5 Framework', '-');` to get your desired results.

```
  @foreach($stores as $store)
    <a href="{{ env('FRONTEND_URL') . "/store/$store->id/$store->name"}}"><label>{{ env('FRONTEND_URL') . "/store/$store->id/".str_slug($store->name)}}  </label></a>
  @endforeach
```

I hope this helps

Comment: can i try some code like this <?php
echo strtolower("Hello WORLD.");
?> ??? its better i think but i didnt know how to make it

Comment: `str_slug('Hello WORLD')` will be resulted as `hello-world`. it will also handle the special characters.

Comment: thanks man but how to make it on my code sorry im really newbie in Laravel

Comment: @SahatRiyanto you can use all plain php function (including strtolower inside plain php tag) as usual depending on your php version inside laravel

Comment: Thanks bro Adnan mumtaz its worked god bless you :DDDDDDD